# Consequenses of DV lottery visa if being rejected on later phase?

Tags: usa, visa, immigration, greencard

If I applied for DV lottery visa and then got selected at first phase but got rejected in later phase like interview or similar(after fillling DS- 260 immigration form). Then will it affect my chances of getting Student visa later.
(especially f1).
Thank you

Comment: What was the reason for your rejection?

Comment: @LorenPechtel  suppose i did not got chance to give interview as allocated visas were issued to other people  before i even got chance for  my interview.

Comment: I wouldn't think that would have any effect--they didn't reject you for anything.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Wouldn't it then signify the immigration intention for my f1 visa which is non immigrant type. Will it not make one hard to explain that he will not go with immigration intent with f1 visas.